# Why am I getting negative SCORE even if i am using scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error'?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Why am I getting negative SCORE even if i am using scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error'?

I tried the following code from apparently the source code:
neg_mean_squared_error_scorer = make_scorer(mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False)

[Source Code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py#L629)

However it doesn't work. And I don't see the point of using it if we are supposed to use scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error'.

Here is the code I used:

```js
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.metrics import \
    r2_score, get_scorer, make_scorer, mean_squared_error
from sklearn.linear_model import \
    Lasso, Ridge, LassoCV,LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import \
    StandardScaler, PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import \
    KFold, RepeatedKFold, GridSearchCV, \
    cross_validate, train_test_split
    
# Features
x1 = np.linspace(-20,20,100)
x1 = np.array(x1).reshape(-1,1)
x2 = pow(x1,2)
x3 = pow(x1,3)
x4 = pow(x1,4)
x5 = pow(x1,5)

# Parameters
beta_0 = 1.75
beta_1 = 5
beta_3 = 0.05
beta_5 = -10.3

eps_mu = 0     # epsilon mean
eps_sigma = sqrt(4)    # epsilon standard deviation
eps_size = 100     # epsilon size

np.random.seed(1)     # Fixing a seed
eps = np.random.normal(eps_mu, eps_sigma, eps_size)
eps = np.array(eps).reshape(-1,1)

y = beta_0 + beta_1*x1 + beta_3*x3 + beta_5*x5 + eps

data = np.concatenate((y,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5), axis = 1)
X = data[:,1:6]
y = data[:,0]

alphas_to_try = np.linspace(0.00000000000000000000000001,0.002,10) ########  To modify  #######
scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error'
#scoring = (mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False)
scorer = get_scorer(scoring)

k = 5
cv = KFold(n_splits = k)
for train_index, test_index in cv.split(data):
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = sc.transform(X_test)
    
validation_scores = []
train_scores = []
results_list = []
test_scores = []

        
for curr_alpha in alphas_to_try:
        regmodel = Lasso(alpha = curr_alpha)

        results = cross_validate(
            regmodel, X, y, scoring=scoring, cv=cv, 
            return_train_score = True)

        validation_scores.append(np.mean(results['test_score']))
        train_scores.append(np.mean(results['train_score']))
        results_list.append(results)

        regmodel.fit(X,y)
        y_pred = regmodel.predict(X_test)
        test_scores.append(scorer(regmodel, X_test, y_test))
        
        chosen_alpha_id = np.argmax(validation_scores)
        chosen_alpha = alphas_to_try[chosen_alpha_id]
        max_validation_score = np.max(validation_scores)
        test_score_at_chosen_alpha = test_scores[chosen_alpha_id]
        
    
print('chosen_alpha:', chosen_alpha) 
print('max_validation_score:', max_validation_score)
print('test_score_at_chosen_alpha:', test_score_at_chosen_alpha)
 
    
plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
sns.lineplot(y = validation_scores, x = alphas_to_try, label = 'validation_data')
sns.lineplot(y = train_scores, x = alphas_to_try, label = 'training_data')
plt.axvline(x=chosen_alpha, linestyle='--')

sns.lineplot(y = test_scores, x = alphas_to_try, label = 'test_data')
plt.xlabel('alpha_parameter')
plt.ylabel(scoring)
plt.title('LASSO Regularisation')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Why the code is not working? Why am I getting negative scores?

Output:
[image]

[image]

What I am supposed to get:
[image]

I am supposed to get something like the screenshot above, but MSE instead of r2 on the y axis.

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, `neg_mean_squared_error` is the **negative** of the mean-squared-error, so negative scores is expected (in fact, it is positive scores that are impossible).

As to the plots, there's a bigger problem.  Your train and validation scores are obtained using `cross_validate`, and are fine.  But your test scores are obtained by fitting the regressor to the entire `X, y` and then scoring that on `X_test, y_test`, a subset of the training set!  So those scores are quite optimistically biased.

A quick check on the scale of the errors: you have a degree-5 polynomial with the original feature taking values between -20 and 20.  So the target takes values on the order of 10^6, and so squared errors may be expected on the order of 10^12.

Comment: About the neg_mean_squared_error it makes sense. But since the purpose is to maximize the neg_mean_squared_error, how to change the Y axis to it goes from 0 to a minus value (in this case to -7) instead of going from -7 to 0. It is important because the purpose is to maximize the neg_mean_squared_error. Therefore, -7 is better than 0...

Comment: About the X,y. You were right. I forgot to train only on the train dataset. However, I didn't understand what did you mean by " So the target takes values on the order of 10^6, and so squared errors may be expected on the order of 10^12". The exponential values are ONLY on my features. I didn't put a "power" on the epsilon. The epsilon allows to generate noise to the data and it follows a normal distribution with mu = 0 and standard deviation = 2.

Comment: The reason sklearn uses _negative_ mse is because all the optimizers are hard-coded to maximize the score given.  Better mse is smaller, so better neg_mse is larger (closer to 0).  -7 is **not** better than 0.  Of course, you are free to manipulate the plot however you see fit.  For the order of errors, I meant the mean-squared-errors, not the error term epsilon.  Your plot has values of -7*10^11, which is what I was trying to comment on.

Comment: Ok I understand now about the -7*10^11. What do you mean by -7 is not better than 0? So, about the neg_mse, you said that the larger this value is, the better it is. So 0 or closer to 0 is the best or maximum value we can expect to get the best neg MSE. Right?